# Can't install Spacy on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: python, spacy

Environment: Windows 7 32-bit (SP1), Python 3.7.3, Microsoft Visual C++ 14.20.27508 (installed from Build Tools)

When I try to install spacy using (pip install -U spacy), after several minutes of message "Installing build dependencies..." I get an error "MS Visual C++ 14 is required" and the installation of Spacy is terminated.

What am I supposed to do to fix the problem? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Many scientific packages for Python on Windows have problems installing through `pip` because most of the time, the supported compiler is not installed.

Instead of fighting with your system and figuring out what compiler you need and where to get it, I just go to Christoph Gohlke's website as he volunteers his time to build the packages properly in a Windows environment and releases the wheels that you can install for `pip`: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#spacy

Choose the Python 3.7, 32-bit version, download it and install the wheel yourself.  In your case, you'll need the `spacy‑2.1.3‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` file.  Download it, and just do:

```
pip install spacy‑2.1.3‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still keep getting errors. I found out that Spacy depends on Blis which is not compiled under Windows 32bit. So I have to say goodbye to Spacy and go to another package (probably NLTK)

Comment: @vitormorev yeah you're really limiting yourself with the 32 bit installation. Sorry.